# I obligate or I am obligate?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Most of the time I do confused with similar like sentences. Explain like I'm 5. 
Thanks in advance.

Research is:
Are our consultants obligated to follow this Code of conduct?
I am obligate to submit time sheet today.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is **obliged**.

*I am obliged to submit a time sheet today.*

Or, you can say, *I am obligated to submit a time sheet today*

**o·blige**

əˈblīj - make (someone) legally or morally bound to an action or course of action.
"doctors are obliged by law to keep patients alive while there is a chance of recovery"
synonyms:   require, compel, bind, constrain, obligate, leave with no option but, force
"it was impractical to oblige taxis to carry infant seats"

Comment: "I am obligated" works just as well. This answer avoids the obvious ELL issue of why "I am obligate" is a solecism.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
This should help you both to end the fight.
http://grammarist.com/usage/obliged-vs-obligated/

Comment: I have 'I am obliged' heard in situations where thanks were owed, the thanks itself being 'I am obliged', like a somewhat archaic 'I owe you one'.

Comment: *legally or morally bound to an action or course of action. "doctors are obliged by law to keep patients alive while there is a chance of recovery" synonyms: require, compel, bind, constrain, obligate, leave with no option but, force "it was impractical to oblige taxis to carry infant seats"*

That seems to fit the criteria to me.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/obliged-vs-obligated/), combined with my own experiences concerning 'I'm obliged', I would say that in the OP's examples, 'obligated' is the most correct (and presumably most common) word to use, as in context of the examples, there are laws and regulations to adhered too. A sense of debt (expressed primarily with 'obliged') does not appear to be applicable or relevant in this business context.

Another reason is that 'obligated' implies consequences in case the obligation is not met, which is not immediately the case with 'oblige'.

Answer (score 1):

"Obligate" is a transitive verb, where the subject of the verb is the one imposing the obligation, and the object of the verb is the one who is somehow restricted by the obligation.

So if you *obligate* someone you impose on them the requirement to do something.  They are then *obligated* (by you) to fulfill that requirement.